# Add schema name dynamically in hibernate mapping file with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using spring + hibernate + oracle in my project. I have LocalSessionFactoryBean as session factory object and mapped different hbm.xml files into my project.

My configuration is as below :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>one.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>two.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>three.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">....</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now I have three mapping files and each refer to different schema. So to map schema name I can provide name at each mapping file like :

```
<hibernate-mapping schema="one">
```

But the problem is I have different schema name based on different environment. So how can I configure it programmatic.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by modifying spring configuration while building mapping.

I created a custom local session factory by extending `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` and added the following method.

```
protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionFactoryBuilder) {
    try {
        sessionFactoryBuilder.buildMappings();
        Iterator<Table> iterator = getConfiguration().getTableMappings();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Table table = iterator.next();
            if (table.getSchema() != null && !table.getSchema().isEmpty()) {
                table.setSchema(mySchemaName);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Exception occurred while building mapping: ", ex);
    }
    return super.buildSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dont provide the schema name in the hibernate config xml file. Create separate .properties files based on your different environment needs. And use them based on environment.
Something like this..

```
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="driverClassName" value="#{db['driverClassName']}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="#{db['url']}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="#{db['username']}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="#{db['password']}"></property>

</session-factory>
```

Comment: Situation is I have only one session factory and data source and I have one schema as primary and accessing tables of other schema from that primary schema.

Comment: which database you are using in your case?

Comment: I am using oracle database

Comment: you can provide the schema name inside the entity and it will work for oracle db

Answer (score 0):

```
you can provide the schema name inside the entity and it will work for oracle db Entity "Account" in schema "ABC" 
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT",schema="ABC")  
class ACCOUNT{
...
}
Entity "CUSTOMER" in schema "XYZ"
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMER",schema="XYZ")  
class CUSTOMER{
...
}
```

Comment: That is fine but I don't want to use hard coded as schema name on different environment (dev , qa) are different. e.g. on local, schema name is one but on qa it is one_1 and I am using xml based hibernate mapping.

Comment: are you using maven complaint project? if yes you can create profile and define your entries. I would suggest focus on env config and how you are building. you can provide the env variables use them in your code.

Comment: I am using gradle but will try with your suggested way and update the same Thanks